# Colocando efeito na caixa de texto

Tags: javascript, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Pessoa minha duvida é mais teorica, gostaria de saber qual é o nome do efeito que damos quando  o input rece foco o nome que esta dentro da caixa ele vai para o topo. A sensação que tenho é quando input recebe foco o diplay some e o label fica visivel só que isso acontece de uma forma leve dando a senssação que palavras esta mundado de lugar e de tamanho.
Imagens como exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Isso já existe no bootstrap? Se existe qual a versão? Por que não conseguiu na documentação do 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse "efeito" foi introduzido primeiramente no Android seguindo as diretrizes do [Material Design](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/). Esse Design System foi desenvolvido pela própria Google e posteriormente adotado por outros frameworks web como o Materialize por exemplo como vc pode ver aqui https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html

Como é um estilo que se popularizou muito não existe uma forma única de ser feito. Para o **Bootstrap 3** vc  não vai encontrar nada feito de forma nativa. Mas para o **Bootstrap 4** existe uma variação chamada **Material Bootstrap** onde existe esse tipo de componente já estilizado, https://mdbootstrap.com/ No caso do **MDB** o efeito é usando um `input + label` provavelmente envolve algum JavaScript tb...

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.7/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
JavaScript
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.7/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

<div class="md-form">
  <input type="email" id="materialLoginFormEmail" class="form-control">
  <label for="materialLoginFormEmail">E-mail</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @hugocls  excelente explicação, Obrigado pelas informações.

Comment: @mba sem problemas jovem, é possível fazer esse efeito também apenas com CSS, aqui tem um exemplo. Ele nem usa Script ou qq outra coisa além do CSS para fazer o efeito https://codepen.io/ibokg/pen/wxNVPj